# Unable to silent print a pdf file from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developping a POS web application from ASP.NET, C#. I would like to silent print pdf file (for invoice receipts) without downloading. In my project, I was able to successfully do the job but once my application deployed in IIS, I can not do it again.

I found this kind of solution on google but as I said, none are working in IIS

```
private void SendToPrinter() 
{
   System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
   process.Refresh(); //process.StartInfo.Arguments = "EasyCoder 91 DT (203 dpi)"; 
   process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 
   process.StartInfo.Verb = "print"; 
   process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\\myfile.pdf"; 
   process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; 
   process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
   process.Start(); 
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
   if (false == p.CloseMainWindow()) 
       p.Kill(); 
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question / problem? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Look, I would like to print my receipts directly to my default printer without downloading the file. Thats my question. I get no error because my code seems to work correctly from my project but once deployed in iis, it doesnt work anymore

Comment: It is still unclear what you want to achieve. When a user clicks a button, you want a receipt to be printed on the **server machine**. Right? If yes, then it should work, if your user has enough privileges to enqueue documents for printing. If you want your document to be printed on **user machine**, then **server-side code** won't help you - you will need to use JS to download file from the server and print it out.

Comment: Dear, I think you have already understood my question and I like your second option of doing with javascript but how? Thats my question.